# Devilbox with Laravel Vite not working in watch-mode

Tags: laravel, docker, docker-compose, vite, devilbox

i want to start use devilbox in laravel-development. But devilbox not connected to vite-server on 5173 port.

Does anyone have a working config for Laravel vite and Devilbox?

I tried change server.hmr.host in vite.config.js to exactly site-domain - it's no effect

```
server: {
        hmr: {
            host: 'test.dvl.to', //your <any_folder_name> host
        },
        watch: {
            usePolling: true,
        },
}
```

I tried follow recommendation from github issues - [SvelteKit, Vite, HMR & Devilbox](https://github.com/cytopia/devilbox/issues/972); [Bug: Laravel with Vite](https://github.com/cytopia/devilbox/issues/797):

1. create new host for hmr-server
2. create backend.cfg with proxy 8080-port
3. configure vite.config.js with ws-protocol and special host for hmr

```
server: {
        hmr: {
            https: false,
            host: 'hmr.dvl.to',
            port: '8080',
            hmr: {
                host: 'hmr.dvl.to',
                clientPort: '8080',
                protocol: 'ws',
                https: false,
            }
        },
        watch: {
            usePolling: true,
        },
}
```

As a result - my app connected to special host for hmr-server, but not reacted to change code. And for update scripts - need to restart vite.